# How to authenticate the WCF Services while Consuming by client

Tags: wcf

How to authenticate credentials of the WCF Services while Consuming by client?

Answer (score 1):

This is both a small and a large topic in my view. 
To understand this there's a fair bit of material to go through, once you know what you're after it can be quite simple.

Resources you can consider -

http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurity

http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/33342